# Management tools for Apache Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

with Datastax's DevOps and DevStudio only supporting DSE now, are there any  community GUIs available for querying & managing Cassandra rings? Thanks

Comment: Just to add to Chris' answer, check if Priam (https://github.com/Netflix/Priam) is enough for what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no single comprehensive suite of Cassandra monitoring and operations tooling outside of DataStax's. There are some community tools to do specific tasks (ie [reaper](https://github.com/thelastpickle/cassandra-reaper) for repairs, prometeus/graphana etc for monitoring), but nothing that does everything. Almost all community tooling is CLI based.

Comment: What about Priam?

Comment: I dont know many who use it but it can handle backup/restore and config management well enough looks like. Can also use chef/ansible/puppet etc with other backup utilities like tablesnap and not be as locked in to its model. Will still need other tools for monitoring, alerting, and repairs. I would actually recommend using whatever tools you already use for your application (ie if you use chef/nagios/grafana/s3, use same for your C* cluster). Repairs and backup/restore are imho the most difficult things to get right. DataStax tools is an easiest to just get everything at once though.